# select row in multi category in mysql

Tags: mysql

Please help to resolve the problem:

I have 2 tables:

```
product (pro_id,cat_id,...)
category(cat_id,cat_name...)
```

I stored cat_id in product as string.

For example:

In table product: `pro_id: 1 & cat_id: 2,3,4; pro_id=2 & cat_id: 2,3,7`
In table category: `cat_id: 1, cat_id: 2, cat_id: 3....`

Now, I want to get all records in product table by `cat_id`.

For example: I want get all product `where cat_id=2`.

Any solution? Thanks for your help

Comment: This is exactly why it's a bad practice to store  lists as column values. Instead there should be a category table and a product_categry join table.

Comment: First, redesign your DB structure, where in product.cat_id will be exactly one category ID.

Comment: i know this solustion. But i want to try store multi category in string and find the way to select product record from specific cat_id in string.

Answer (score 0):

Just put 2 as a string i.e. `'2'`

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE cat_id = '2';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search the products by a column from the category table do:

```
SELECT *, category.cat_name from product 
JOIN category on category.cat_id = CAST(product.cat_id AS UNSIGNED)
where category.cat_name like '%myname%';
```

I will recommend to you to create a index for the column product.cat_id, or i think you will have serious performance troubles in your database...

That is it!